# Paypal integration to third party

Tags: paypal

I am integrating paypal with my application. In my application two type of user are there. On who can sell their product on my site and second type of user are public user who can buy the product.

When some on buy product on my site is it possible to directly transfer the money to customer who already have paypal account i.e without transferring money to my paypal account.

Comment: use adaptive payment

Answer (score 0):

[Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) would be a better experience for the buyers in a typical web store scenario.  It consists of 3 API calls:

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

In the SEC request and the DECP request you would include the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter and set the value to the email address or PayPal account ID of the PayPal account you'd like the payment to go to.

You won't have to worry about setting up permissions or anything like that, either.

If you happen to be working with PHP, my [class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make the API calls very simple for you.